# how to wrap xml with header

Tags: php, web-services

I'm trying to make a web-service request (WSDL).

```
$s = new soapclient("http://www.wb-service-address.com",array('wsdl'));
$HotelInfo = new stdClass;

<HotelInfo softwareID="123" SessionId="153">
     <Hotel  ID="103" /> 
</HotelInfo>

$HotelInfo->xmlRequest = $paramsStr;
$result = $s->__call("SubmitXmlString",array($HotelInfo));
$obj_pros = get_object_vars($result);
$hotel_full_xml =  $obj_pros['SubmitXmlStringResult'];  
$hotel_full_xml = simplexml_load_string($hotel_full_xml);
```

How the request will look like if i want to  wrap the XML with a header?

Comment: I dont fully understand the question. What are your inputs and what is your desired output?

Comment: I want to wrap the XML with the login / authentication details (user+password) - @paskl